# Error while installing canvas npm package on windows

Tags: node.js, canvas, npm

I've installed nodejs on windows and tried adding the canvas module using the following command

```
npm install canvas
```

I get the following error message

```
Error: Can't find Python executable "D:\Python", you can set the PYTHON env variable. at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
```

Comment: Do you have `Python` installed in your machine?

Comment: **yes**, installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your environmental variables to add `Python` to your existing `PATH` variable, Follow the below steps,

Goto

```
Start => Run => (Type) rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables (Press Enter)
```

Select an entry called "**Path**" under "**User variables**" and click on the "**Edit**" button which will open another popup where you will have an option to add new path variable (Using the "New" button). Please add your `Python` executable path over there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: After configuring the **python** path the error was changed,  **KeyError: '2017'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\Dipin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:239:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134**

Comment: @DipinRajC May I know your `python` version?

Comment: Version **2.7**